# value of natural logarithm

Tags: c

I want to find value of In(x) without using math.h function

I am following this formula which I found in my math book:

```
log(m) base e = 2[ (m-1/m+1) + (1/3) * (m-1/m+1)^3 + (1/5) * (m-1/m+1)^5 + ... ]
```

Here is my code:

```
i = 3;
logx = 0 ;
ty = (x-1)/(x+1) ;
do
{
    logx = logx + ty ;
    tty = ty ;
    ty = (ty * ((x-1)/(x+1)) * ((x-1)/(x+1))) / i ;
    i = i + 2 ;
} while(tty - ty > 0.0000005 );
logx = 2*logx ;
printf("\n ln (%g) = %g \n", x, logx);
```

but this shows `ln(2) = 0.691916` instead of `0.693147` and `ln(3) = 1.08765` instead of `1.098612` etc. What is wrong?

Comment: PEOPLE! there's an error in the algorithm, this has nothing to do with convergence, cancellation or whatever!

Answer (score 4):

You should not divide by i and then assign to ty, devide by i after the addition, i.e. `logx = logx + ty / i`.

**Edit** this should work:

```
i=1;   // (i.e. not 3)
logx = 0 ;
ty = (x-1)/(x+1) ;
do
{
    logx = logx + ty / i;
    tty = ty ;
    ty = (ty * ((x-1)/(x+1)) * ((x-1)/(x+1)));
    i = i + 2 ;
} while(tty - ty > 0.0000005 );
```

Comment: Yes it is.  mathoverflow is for reseach.  This is very much an implementation question.

Comment: Yup. That looks better. And although its outside the scope of the question I personally would prefer to see the logx assignment happen at the end of the loop. Otherwise you waste your last loop (you get the next ty but then never use it).

Comment: That, plus storing `(x-1)/(x+1) * (x-1)/(x+1)` once outside the loop. `gcc -O3` apparently doesn't notice that the factor is the same every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Actually what OP's computing is

> [$2\sum_{n=1,n\text{ odd}}^\infty\frac1{n!!}\left(\frac{m-1}{m+1}\right)^n = \sqrt{2\pi} \exp\left(\frac12\left(\frac{m-1}{m+1}\right)^2\right)\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{m-1}{m+1}\right)$ http://mathcache.appspot.com/?tex=%5cpng%5c%5b2%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%2Cn%5Ctext%7B%20odd%7D%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac1%7Bn%21%21%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5En%20%3D%20%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%5Cexp%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac12%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5E2%5Cright%29%5Coperatorname%7Berf%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt2%7D%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5c%5d](http://mathcache.appspot.com/?tex=%5cpng%5c%5b2%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%2Cn%5Ctext%7B%20odd%7D%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac1%7Bn%21%21%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5En%20%3D%20%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%5Cexp%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac12%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5E2%5Cright%29%5Coperatorname%7Berf%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt2%7D%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5c%5d)

instead of

> [$2\sum_{n=1,n\text{ odd}}^\infty\frac1{n}\left(\frac{m-1}{m+1}\right)^n = 2\tanh^{-1}\frac{m-1}{m+1} = \ln m$ http://mathcache.appspot.com/?tex=%5cpng%5c%5b2%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%2Cn%5Ctext%7B%20odd%7D%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac1%7Bn%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5En%20%3D%202%5Ctanh%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cln%20m%5c%5d](http://mathcache.appspot.com/?tex=%5cpng%5c%5b2%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%2Cn%5Ctext%7B%20odd%7D%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac1%7Bn%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%5Cright%29%5En%20%3D%202%5Ctanh%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cfrac%7Bm-1%7D%7Bm%2b1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cln%20m%5c%5d)

BTW, it's better to factor out the `((x-1)/(x+1)) * ((x-1)/(x+1))` to avoid recomputing it. (The compiler may or may not treat this as a loop invariant and take it out.)

```
double ty = (x-1)/(x+1);
double p = ty * ty;
int i = 1;
double logx = 0;
do {
  logx += ty / i;
  tty = ty;
  ty *= p;
  i += 2;
} while (tty/(i-2) - ty/i > 5e-6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C implementation is not correct for the algorithm.

```
log(m) base e = 2[ (m-1/m+1) + (1/3) * (m-1/m+1)^3 + (1/5) * (m-1/m+1)^5 + ... ]
                                ^^^ what is this      ^^^ and this
```

Your algorithm:

```
i = 3;
logx = 0 ;
ty = (x-1)/(x+1) ;
do
{
    logx = logx + ty ;
    tty = ty ;
    ty = (ty * ((x-1)/(x+1)) * ((x-1)/(x+1))) / i ; 
//  ^^ when i = 3 ty after this line = ((x-1)/(x+1) * ((x-1)/(x+1))^2) / 3
//     when i = 5 ty after this line = ((((x-1)/(x+1)^3) / 3) * ((x-1)/(x+1))^2) / 5 
//                                   = ((x-1)/(x+1)^5) / 15 <<< wrong divisor (see above, should be 5)
//     and it gets worse for each iteration of the loop
    i = i + 2 ;
} while(tty - ty > 0.0000005 );
logx = 2*logx ;
printf("\n ln (%g) = %g \n", x, logx);
```

Comment: thank you JeremyP. You perfectly showed me where I am doing wrong.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

you're approximating a function with a finite number of iterations (the stop condition is tty-ty > ...); decrease the 0.00000005 and you should obtain better precision

then you might run into numerical precision problems, so try using double instead of float if you're not already doing so

finally remember that generally logarithms are irrational numbers so they just can't be represented with a finite number of digits

Answer (score -1):

ISTR that the rate of convergence of log series are notoriously slow.